# href losing parameter value when forming link from parent

Tags: html, href

i have a url:

```
"http://localhost:8000/group/2"
```

In the page i have:

```
<a href="groupSpecific/1" class="button">GroupSpecific1</a>
```

What i would expect to happen is the link to form: `"http://localhost:8000/group/2/groupSpecific/1"`

For some reason the link formed is: `"http://localhost:8000/group/groupSpecific/1"`

How can i keep the parameter from disappearing from the url?

Comment: What happens if you add a '/' after 2 in the URL?

Comment: You probably have a `<base>` tag in your `<head>`

Comment: you sir Professorval are a genius, all problems fixed, thank you!!